# Streamtape remote Upload return status 200 but the remote upload shows error on Streamtape website

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, api, axios

I'm Using axios to remote upload videos to streamtape server but i dont know why its not working i followed the documentation on streamtape API page but still cant figure out what is wrong with it. Can someone please check out my code and help me understand what am i doing wrong.

```
<script>
        function myFunction() {
            var apiKey = "7975f4ed########0cfef";
            var apiPass = "8OvJO9##########VqZ";

            axios
                .post(
                    "https://api.streamtape.com/remotedl/add?login=7975##############680cfef&key=8O########VqZ&url=https://streamta.pe/get_video?id=vLGqPqm8xwTYRj&expires=1611399962&ip=GRysD0ESKxSHDN&token=bWNmLLoaG99b&stream=1"
                )
                .then((responce) => {
                    console.log(responce);
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    console.log(err);
                });
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! From the context i can only recommend you try to add `Content-Type: multipart/form-data'`  as the second argument of the post call ```axios.post('url', {headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}})```

Comment: @maljukan Tried adding headers but still didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: I was using wrong url to upload. this is the correct url to use for remote uploading. `https://streamtape.com/e/{video_id}`